# EasyMock expect method is always return null despite setting a new Object in .andReturn

Tags: java, easymock

I have my source code as:

```
response = getRequestService().retrieveResponse(baseRequest);  
data = response.getStoredData(); ---> (1)
```

And I have written my Test Case as :

```
RequestService requestService = EasyMock.createNiceMock(RequestService .class);  
BaseRequest baseRequest = new BaseRequest();  
BaseResponse response = new BaseResponse();  
expect(requestService .retrieveResponse(EasyMock.eq(baseRequest))).andReturn(response)
replay(requestService );
```

However, when I run my test I am always getting a `NullPointerException` at line 1.

Can somebody please help me on how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The first place I would look would be to make sure the `getRequestService()` call returns a reference to your mock request service. It looks like you haven't yet defined that behavior, and the call to `getRequestService()` is returning `null`.

Comment: Changing this line                                                  expect(requestService .retrieveResponse(EasyMock.eq(baseRequest))).andReturn(response)       to                                                                   expect(requestService .retrieveResponse((BaseRequest)EasyMock.anyObject())).andReturn(response)                                                                worked for me. But I am not sure if this is the right way to go cause I am not enforcing the Object type in the mock call